# handleMethodArgumentNotValid not working in spring 5

Tags: spring

I use spring 5 and for validation, when I use bindig result its ok to get fields have error, but when I want to use @Controller advice as following, handleMethodArgumentNotValid not hit and working when test with Postman and just error 400 bad request returned.I cant catch the handleMethodArgumentNotValid excprion.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static final MerchantManagerLogger logger =
            MerchantManagerLogger.getLogger(GlobalControllerExceptionHandler.class);


    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
 
        return super.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(ex, headers, status, request);
    }
```

and my controller :

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/tax/changeTerminalCashRegister",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ChangeTerminalTaxResponseDto changeCashRegisterStatus(@Valid @RequestBody TaxChangeCashRegisterStatusReqDto requestBody) {
//        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
//            bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
//        }

        return changeTerminalTaxService.convertCashRegisterStatus(requestBody);
    }
```

Comment: And what behaviour you expected? As default when this exception is caught status will be 400. [Link to git srping](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java#L167)

Comment: I can not catch the exception. handleMethodArgumentNotValid not hit

Comment: Try to debug, place debug point to your `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler#handleMethodArgumentNotValid()`, does it stop there?

Comment: No, it dose not

Comment: Does your `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler` available for `ComponentScan`?

Comment: Yes its available